# Como converter um ficheiro CSV para HDF5 sem necessidade de código, é possível?

Tags: csv, hdf5

Preciso de converter um ficheiro `.csv` em `hdf5` para utilizar no `RapidMiner` para criar modelos. No entanto, já estive a procura e só encontro soluções utilizando Python e outras linguagens de programação.

Como não tenho conhecimentos em nenhuma das linguagens existe alguma forma de conversão sem utilizar linguagens de programação?

Obrigada.

Comment: O site é justamente sobre programação, indicação de ferramentas desse tipo é fora de escopo. De qq forma, o pessoal pode ajudar nos comentários.

Comment: Oi,

esta é uma tradução do Google. Desculpe se não é perfeito.

Se eu entendi sua pergunta corretamente, você pode simplesmente usar o operador "Ler CSV". Com isso, você pode importar o arquivo CSV para o RapidMiner. Em seguida, você pode usar o operador "Write HDF5" para converter os dados e gravá-los no disco. Você pode encontrar a extensão HDF5 no mercado RapidMiner.